# Compare xml schema column for update script

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there any way to compare two xml column schemas so I can trigger a schema update for that column?

I know how to query the schemas existence, but is there anyway I can compare it with a schema that I might update with?

```
select C2.name
from sys.columns as C1
  inner join sys.xml_schema_collections as C2
    on C1.xml_collection_id = C2.xml_collection_id
where C1.object_id = object_id('TableName') and
      C1.name = 'ColumnName' and C2.name = 'SchemaName'
```

like it would work this way:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (< Actual schema compare >)
BEGIN
    --ALTER COLUMN to xml
    --DROP SCHEMA
    --CREATE SCHEMA
    --ALTER COLUMN to xml with schema again
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xml_schema_namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190316.aspx) will give you the schemas in a collection as XML.

The XML that is stored in SQL Server is not exactly the same as the version that was used to create the schema. Comments, white spaces, and annotations are removed so you have to create a temp collection in SQL Server for the schema you want to compare against and extract that schema using `xml_schema_namespace` as well. XML is not directly comparable so you have to cast the XML to `nvarchar(max)` before you compare the schema collections.

A stored procedure that checks the schema collation could look something like this.

```
create procedure dbo.CompareSchema 
  @NewSchema xml,
  @RelationalSchema sysname,
  @XMLSchemaCollectionName sysname,
  @Diff bit out
as
begin
  create xml schema collection dbo.__TempCollaction as @NewSchema;

  if cast(xml_schema_namespace(@RelationalSchema, @XMLSchemaCollectionName) as nvarchar(max)) = 
       cast(xml_schema_namespace('dbo', '__TempCollaction') as nvarchar(max))
    set @Diff = 0;
  else
    set @Diff = 1;   

  drop xml schema collection dbo.__TempCollaction;
end
```